# Confusion about Access Specifier

Tags: c++

I am currently reading the book *SFML Game Development*. I got it because throughout the book one will develop an entire game using the SFML API and (more importantly) C++ 11. I really enjoy being introduced to all the new features by actually using them instead of reading about them reference-style.

However, there is one tiny part of the code that I really don't get. (Maybe my failure to comprehend doesn't even have to do anything with C++ 11, it certainly isn't related to SFML.)

Please take a look at `SceneNode.hpp`:

```
class SceneNode
{
    public:
        // ...
        void attachChild(std::unique_ptr<SceneNode> child);
        // ...
    private:
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<SceneNode>> mChildren;
        SceneNode* mParent;
};
```

As you might have already guessed, `SceneNode` represents a node within a very simple tree. What I don't understand is the implementation of `SceneNode::attachChild`:

```
void SceneNode::attachChild(std::unique_ptr<SceneNode> child)
{
    child->mParent = this; // How can mParent be accessed? It's private?!
    this->mChildren.push_back(std::move(child));
}
```

As you can see, the method receives a `std::unique_ptr` that points to the `SceneNode` to be attached *by value*, thus claiming ownership of it. However, `child`'s member `mParent` is still private, **why can we access it?**

I feel that there is an embarrassingly easy solution, I couldn't figure it out, though...

Comment: `private` doesn't mean "accessible only by this object" it means "accessible only to this class".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, this isn't specific to C++11. An object of class type is able to access the private members of objects of the same class type. That is, members are `private` to a class, not to an object. You are able to access private members of a `SceneNode` from another `SceneNode`.

We have access specifiers for the sake of encapsulation - to decouple the internal implementation of a class from the code that uses that class. Since a class already knows its own internal implementation (its member functions are tightly coupled to its data members), encapsulation is not lost by allowing objects of the same type to access each others private members.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response! The first OOP language I learned was Java, where a `private` member can only be accessed by other members within the same instance/object. Just out of curiosity: In C++, is there a way to make a member `private` to an instance/object?

Comment: @baerenfaenger Then I think you'll be surprised that [the same is true in Java](http://ideone.com/aNfygK). And no, there's no object-level access specifiers.

Comment: I cannot believe I have missed that! Thank you very much, again!